# Body of post request not sending correctly

Tags: elixir, plug

I am writing a POST request that should send some information to a REST api using elixir, this information should be able to be accessed in the conn.body_params, however it appears empty.

My code is as follows:

```elixir
conn2 = conn(:post, gameID<>"/guesses", Poison.encode!(%{guess: "p"}))
      |> GameRouter.call()
      assert conn2.status == 201
```

My plug also has the following configuration:

```elixir
plug Plug.Parsers, parsers: [:urlencoded, :multipart, :json],  pass: ["*/*"], json_decoder: Poison
```

How should it be written as to actually send the information in the POST request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the `content-type: application/json` header so that `Plug.Parsers` will know to use the json parser.

```elixir
conn2 =
  conn(:post, gameID <> "/guesses", Poison.encode!(%{guess: "p"}))
  |> put_req_header("content-type", "application/json")
  |> GameRouter.call()
```

The `pass: ["*/*"]` is telling `Plug.Parsers` to ignore all content types it doesn't know about. If you remove that, you will get `Plug.Parsers.UnsupportedMediaTypeError`, which would have helped you identify the problem.